# How to add assignment property to existing object literal expression in typescript compiler api?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to add `bar: true` to `x` object using typescript AST.

This code cerates the `bar: true`:

```
 factory.createPropertyAssignment(
   factory.createIdentifier("bar"),
   factory.createTrue()
 );
```

I know I need to return this function in order to add it to AST. if I do so then the problem is the code will override the `foo: true`.

Any ideas how to add `bar: true` without lose the `foo: true`?

The code:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

const code = `
const x = {
  foo: true
})
`;

const node = ts.createSourceFile("x.ts", code, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);

const printer = ts.createPrinter({ newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed });

export const add = (context) => (rootNode) => {
  function visit(node) {
    const { factory } = context;

    // if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression) {
    //   return factory.createPropertyAssignment(
    //     factory.createIdentifier("bar"),
    //     factory.createTrue()
    //   );
    // }

    return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);
  }

  return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};

const result = ts.transform(node, [add]);

// console.log({ result });
const transformedSourceFile = result.transformed[0];

const out = printer.printFile(transformedSourceFile);

console.log({ out });
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-dhawan-j40yy?file=/src/index.js:0-761)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in typescript, `node.properties` is readonly. The type-safe way is to use the `factory.update*()` methods when you want to mutate the current node and return it:

```js
export const add: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = (context) => (rootNode) => {
    function visit(node: ts.Node): ts.VisitResult<ts.Node> {
        const { factory } = context;

        // using the provided typeguard to narrow the node kind
        if (ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(node)) {
            return factory.updateObjectLiteralExpression(node, [
                    // include the existing properties
                    ...node.properties,
                    // add your generated property
                    factory.createPropertyAssignment(
                        factory.createIdentifier("bar"),
                        factory.createTrue()
                    )
                ]
            );
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);
    }

    return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the PropertyAssignment node from the visitor for ObjectLiteralExpression node which replaces the complete Object literal.

Instead, you can update the properties member of this node to contain your new property:

```
export const add = (context) => (rootNode) => {
  function visit(node) {
    const { factory } = context;

    if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression) {
      // Update node.properties ------>
      node.properties.push(
        factory.createPropertyAssignment(
          factory.createIdentifier("bar"),
          factory.createTrue()
        )
      );
      return node;
    }

    return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);
  }

  return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};
```